# Does iMessage have BCC?

Tags: ios, messages, contacts, ipod-touch

Does iMessage have the ability to send a message as a BCC (blind carbon copy) to a group, like email services do (Gmail and Apple Mail)?

Sometimes I have a message that I want many people to receive but, I don't want to send it as a group because then each recipient automatically gets the contact info for everyone in the group. Though sending a message by copy and paste to a group is also a waiste of time. So, I'm looking for a solution.

I do know that there are some 3d party apps Like Freetone, textPlus, and maybe Text Free, that provide a feature that lets me send a message to a group but as individual messages to each person.